# parse url to get id using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url, backbone.js, url-routing

I am writing a router which will parse the url and redirect to necessary components in the code, when I change my url and pass object id with it, I want to parse it using regular expression and route it to get that object by id.

```
mysite.com/blah#path=folder/?folderId=klafjlka
```

How do I parse this url using javscript regex and route it to that folder

With reference to backbone, I want to write a code which does this, but I'm not using backbone

```
routes : { "folder/:id" : "handler" },
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: so far I have been able to route static urls, such as /albumList but I don't really know how to write conditions for dynamic urls where we are passing a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to find that using .split normally creates much more readable code in these situations.

If you use window.location.hash to get your data originally, you'll be left with

```
#path=folder/?folderId=klafjlka
```

Eliminating the first lot of un-needed stuff. The rest can be simply done with a split and a looped split.

```
//Remove the initial hash from the window.location.hash
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1),
    //Split it down so we have ["path=folder","folderId=klafjlka"]
    paramSplit = hash.split("/?");

var params = {};
for (var x=0; x<paramSplit.length; x++){
  //Split it at the equals
  var split = paramSplit[x].split("=");
  params[split[0]]=split[1];
}

console.log(params);
```

Params should return

```
{
  path: "folder",
  folderId: "klafjlka"
}
```

Which is easy to use for whatever your purposes are.

Answer (score 0):

If your url is in a string and has always the same structure

```
var url = 'mysite.com/blah#path=folder/?folderId=klafjlka';
var re = /#path=(.+?)\?folderId=(.*)/i
var args = url.match(re);
var path = args[1];
var id = args[2];
```

this searches for `#path=` and captures the following characters until `?` and then searches for `?folderId=` and captures everything else.

Now `path` will contain `folder/` and `id` wil contain `klafjlka`.